# Calculate correctly the working days in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this a table with some user id events (**starting table**).

In this table there is a Event_Id = 1 that refers to a Local Holiday (it's not a working day).

[image]

**I need to fill the column 'Event_1'** to be able to calculate correctly the WorkingDays (**result table - below**).

- In each row where the Event_Id <> 1,  the Event_1 column should have
  a 1 if the corresponding user as matching Event_Id = 1 between the
  StartDate and EndDate, else it should be 0.
- If the row in analysis as Event_id = 1 the value in Event_1 column
  should be 0 as well.

**I already have a function that calculates the WorkingDays.**

[image]

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: Please tag with which database platform. What have you attempted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You can move the filter to the `on` clause and get rid of the subquery:

```
Select e1.*,
       (Case When e2.StartDate Is not Null and e1.Event_Id = 1 then 0
             When e2.StartDate Is not Null Then 1 
             Else 0
        End) As [Local_Holiday]
From [plann].[Events] e left Join
     [plann].[Events] e2
     on e2.Event_Id = 1 and
        e2.StartDate Between e1.StartDate and e1.EndDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution, but I would like to know if you think it's the best way to do it.

```
Select T1.*,
    Case
        When t2.StartDate Is not Null and t1.Event_Id = 1 then 0
        When t2.StartDate Is not Null Then 1 
        Else 0
    End As [Local_Holiday]
From 
    [plann].[Events]  as T1 left Join
    (Select StartDate
        From [plann].[Events] 
        Where Event_Id = 1 ) as T2 ON T2.StartDate Between T1.StartDate and T1.EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the data results between your blue table and green table, it appears that the value of Event_1 is the number of days assigned to the “Local Holiday.”

If a “Local Holiday” will only EVER equal one day and all “Local Holiday” records apply to any user whose vacation coincides with the holiday, then Gordon’s solution works (and I like how he gets rid of the subquery).

However, you may need to address other considerations.

Per your data results, each user with a Local Holiday that occurs during their vacation has a separate record indicating this, which means that the existence of a holiday record per user matters. If so, include an additional join for [User Ud].

```
LEFT JOIN plann.Events e2 ON e2.Event_Id = 1 
    AND e2.StartDate BETWEEN e1.StartDate AND e1.EndDate 
    AND e2.[User Ud] = e1.[User Ud]
```

WITHOUT the [User Ud] join, if user 22 has a holiday within his vacation time, then the holiday is recognized—but his data result is inconsistent compared to the others because he does not have a record assigned to him with an Event_Id = 1.

WITH the [User Ud] join, you get consistent results, but this leads to design issues and limitations.

Suppose a “Local Holiday” pertains to all users (typical). If so, I suggest creating a separate holiday table. Accessing the table for applicable dates ensures that all holidays are recognized for all users with an applicable vacation date range.

I modified the script removing the assumption that a holiday is always one day (Canada, the UK, and other countries have two public holidays in a row). This consideration led me back to using a subquery.

```
SELECT
    e1.[User Ud],
    e1.Event_Id,
    e1.Event,
    e1.StartDate,
    e1.EndDate,
    CASE
        WHEN e1.Event_Id = 1
        THEN 0
        WHEN e2.[User Ud] IS NOT NULL
        THEN Number_Days
        ELSE 0
    END AS Holiday_Nmbr_Days,
    WorkingDays

FROM plann.Events e1

LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        [User Ud],
        DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate) + 1 AS Number_Days,
        StartDate
    FROM plann.Events
    WHERE Event_Id = 1) AS e2 ON e2.Startdate BETWEEN e1.Startdate AND e1.EndDate
        AND e2.[User Ud] = e1.[User Ud] /*Exclude if not applicable*/
```

Comment: Dawn, I understand what your are saying . This example is just a subset of the main table events. I have another table for all Nacional holidays, that report to everybody, Because the business is spread all over the country, the Local Holiday reports to the Holyday where the user work,  so I decided to treat this Holiday as an event, like vacation and many others. In the example I chose not to put the Local Holiday for User_Id 22, but I could have put. Thanks.